# INSERT 0..n records into table 'A' based on content of table 'B' in MySql 5

Tags: sql, mysql

Using MySql 5, I have a task where I need to update one table based on the contents of another table.

For example, I need to add 'A1' to table 'A' if table 'B' contains 'B1'.  I need to add 'A2a' and 'A2b' to table 'A' if table 'B' contains 'B2', etc..  In our case, the value in table 'B' we're interested is an enum.

Right now I have a stored procedure containing a series of statements like:

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT 'A1'
FROM B
WHERE B.Value = 'B1';
--Repeat for 'B2' -> 'A2a'; 'B2' -> 'A2b'; 'B3' -> 'A3', etc...
```

Is there a nicer more DRY way of accomplishing this?

**Edit:**
There may be values in table 'B' that have no equivalent value for table 'A'.

**Edit:**
Example

Given Table B

```
+-------+
| Value |
+-------+
| B1    |
| B1    |
| B2    |
| B3    |
| FOO   |
+-------+
```

Expect Table A

```
+-------+
| Value |
+-------+
| A1    |
| A2a   |
| A2b   |
| A3    |
+-------+
```

Comment: What do you done to table A if there's no equivalent?  Will you know these cases beforehand?

Comment: If table `B` has five records with `Value = "B2"`, will you insert two records into `A` (one for each distinct mapping you have), or ten records (mappings times no. source rows)?  The answers so far seem to assume the latter, but it's not clear that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @pilcrow, I may want to perform no action on some values in table B.  So, given your example, If table B has five records with Value = "B2" (and no "B1" or "B3"), then only "A2a" and "A2b" should be added to A.  Dumb, yes, but that's the situation.  There may be no elegant way of doing it, but if there is, I'd love to know it.

Comment: @Robert, yes, but *how many* `"A2a"` and `"A2b"` records will you insert into table `A`? :)  Please show us an example of a one-column table `B` (the input) and the expected one-column table `A` (the desired output).

Comment: @pilcrow, Sorry for the confusion, if 'B1' is in table B twice, I only  want 'A1' once.  In my specific case I know that 'B1' can only be in table B once, but solving for the generic case is probably more useful for all.  Example tables added.

Comment: @pilcrow, Thanks for putting in the effort to help me clarify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider creating a table that contains the test/result combinations you want, eg:

```
TABLE Tests

Test  |  Result
----------------
B1    |  A1
B2    |  A2a
B2    |  A2b
B3    |  A3
```

Then you can inner join this table to TABLE_B and read out the resulting Result column to determine the values to insert into TABLE_A:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_B.Result
FROM TESTS, TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_B.Value = TESTS.Test
```

Comment: The OP may (or may not) want that to be `INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT ...` .. I've asked for clarification in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, distinct is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looking at your answer, I see that I was trying to encode data into my SQL commands rather than expressing it as data like you have done in your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN b.value = 'B1' THEN 'A1'
         WHEN b.value = 'B2' THEN 'A2a'
       END
  FROM TABLE_B b
```

### I need to add 'A2a' and 'A2b' to table 'A' if table 'B' contains 'B2'

---

Sorry, one value can be returned.  A switch statement allows fall through cases, but wouldn't return more than one value either.

Comment: @Ponies, this is cool, and I was unaware of the CASE statement, however, as you state, it doesn't solve the problem fully.  +1 still.